# Proper way to ask if mysql_num_rows in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

Because mysql_num_rows returns false if there are no rows returned, would it be best to do:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE something = 'this'"); 
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($result) { }
```

Or should I do:

```
if ($result >= 1) { }
```

Comment: ... I love how everyone has a dozen different ways of coming up with the same simple solution. I guess there is never a clear-cut answer with PHP/MySQL.

Comment: please dont use mysql instead use PDO  or prepare statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper one

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE something = 'this'"); 
if (mysql_num_rows($result)){
    //there are results
}
```

however, you could do this easier, without checking

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE something = 'this'"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    //there are results
}
```

Please. Give your variables proper names

Comment: Thanks, I like that first example.

Comment: downside to the second one is that you are not able to display something else in case no records are present, which is desirable in numerous of cases. But if it isn't, it is a good practice!

Answer (score 5):

The proper way would be using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) instead of the ancient `mysql_*` functions:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT item_id FROM Items WHERE name = :param');
$stmt->bindParam( ':param', $some_name, PDO::PARAM_STR, 127 );
if ( $stmt->execute() )
{
   echo $stmt->rowCount();
   var_dump( $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ));
}
```

Comment: +1, mysql_* was written for MySQL version 4 and older. Time to refresh

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't return `false` if no rows are returned, it returns `false` in the case of an error.  You can handle that this way:

```
 if ($result === false) {
    /* An error occurred - do something */
 } else {
    /* $result is set to some number >= 0 */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think honestly that

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE something = 'this'"); 
if (mysql_num_rows($query)!==FALSE){
    //there are results
}
```

is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Count will return a value, and you cannot count and then call mysql_num_rows. It is either one of the other.

You could do

```
$isExist = mysql_query("Select count(id) from ..."); 
$r = mysql_fetch_array($isExist);
if($r['COUNT(id)'] > 0){
//item exists
}else{
//item doesnt exist
}
```

If alternatively you can do the query as:

```
$isexist = mysql_query("select * from wcddl_filehosts where downloadid = '".$download[id]."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($isExists)>0){
//we have items
}else{
//we dont have items
}
```